# value of every key is getting overwritten by last key's value in flask post method of multiple files upload

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, post

I am creating an API for extracting text data from image using machine learning and ocr and getting the response in dictionary for each image. However, when I am adding the dictionary as value to its key(which is image's name), all the values in each key is getting overwritten by last key's value. Please see the images to understand the problem. I don't have much experience with flask so any suggestion might be helpful.
[flask post method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9mwU.png)
[printed dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8gvU.png)

Answer (score 0):

solved it, just had to use copy() function while adding dictionary as value